# Из массива uint8_t в маcсив char на языке "C"

Tags: c, массивы, строки, sprintf

имеем:

```
сhar str[200];
```

и есть:

```
uint8_t buffer [len]; //(какой-то длинны/с какими-то данными)
```

Нужно в `str` передать данные форматом `%02X`

Есть ли решение?
что то типа этого

```
sprintf(str, "%02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X", buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[3], buffer[4], buffer[5], buffer[6], buffer[7]);
```

но у меня `buffer` может быть разного размера. Он определяется размером `Len`

Answer (score 2):

Победил сам) Кому может пригодится

`for(int i=0;i<Len;i++){ sprintf(&str[i*3], "%02X ", buffer[i]); }`

Comment: В конце итоговой строки ещё пробел удалить надо `str[3*Len-1]=0;`

Comment: добавлю ещё, что если нет гарантии, что размер буфера заведомо больший необходимого (`Len*3+1`), то стоит использовать `snprintf()` и обрабатывать ошибки...